# React Jest test didn't recognize import Alias

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm executing a basic React Jest test in a Button component and the test don't recognize an import.

Does anyone have any idea why the test fail in this import ?

**Component:**

```
import ...
import ... from 'styled-components';
import ... from 'styled-tools';

import {Icon} from 'xpto';
import {Default as theme} from 'Themes';

import * as mixins from '../../../config/styles/mixins';
... 
&:hover{
    background-color: #000;
    border: 1px solid ${theme.colors.primary};
    color: ${theme.colors.primary};
    & svg:not([fill="none"]):not([fill="#000"]) {
      fill: ${theme.colors.primary};
    }
    & .nohover svg {
      fill: ${({color}) => color};
    }
...
```

**Error:**

```
FAIL  .../Button/index.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'Themes' from 'index.js'

       5 | 
       6 | import {Icon} from 'xpto';
    >  7 | import {Default as theme} from 'Themes';
         | ^
       8 | 
       9 | import * as mixins from '../../../config/styles/mixins';
      10 | 

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:221:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (.../Button/index.js:7:1)
```

**Jest test file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Button from './index';
describe('Button', () => {  
  it('should render correctly with no props', () => {
    const component = mount(<Button/>); 
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jest couldn't resolve your index.js in Themes folder. You can fix it by using one of two ways below:

1. Tell Jest how to resolve your file:

   - setting in package.json

```
"jest": {
   "modulePaths": ["path to src folder which contains Themes folder"],
   ...
}
```

Check out [this tutorial](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack.html)

2. Set NODE_PATH in .env file

```
NODE_PATH=src/ # src folder contains Themes folder
```